# Get the p-values from the lm function for grouped data

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr, lm

I am trying to fit a model for each segment in my data using the `lm()` function in conjunction with the `plyr` package because my data is grouped by a key.

I've managed to run the model and get the coefficients along with the R^2 & adj r-squared but I am struggling with the p-values.

```
library("plyr")
#Sample data
test_data <- data.frame(key = c("a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b"),
y = c(100,180,120,60,140,200,220,240,260,280),
x1 = c(50,60,79,85,90,133,140,120,160,170),
x2 =  c(20,18,47,16,15,25,30,25,20,15))

#model
model_1 <- dlply(test_data, .(key), 
    function(test_data) lm(y ~ x1 +     x2,data = test_data))

#coefficients
ldply(model_1, coef)

#adj r-squared
ldply(model_1, function(x) summary(x)$r.squared)
```

I've tried this which gets me the key and the p-value but it doesn't have the names of the variables which I need to be able to merge the output with the coefficients from the model later.

```
#p-values but missing the variable names
ldply(model_1, function(x) summary(x)$coefficients)[,c(1,5)]
```

I've tried to fit the models using `Do` and then `tidy` from the `dplyr` package and this works fine with a small data set because it actually returns everything I need but my actual data contains over 1,000 different segments and RStudio end up crashing.

Comment: `nlme::lmList` might be interesting for you as well. Check it out! Apart from that, I am very surprised to hear that the `dplyr::do` approach combined with `broom::tidy` crashes. Any chance you can recreate the error?

Comment: @coeffeinjunky - apologies, by 'crashes' I mean RStudio becomes unresponsive, there was no 'error' as such.  When I run dplyr on my data set it gets through the 1000+ models in around 4 seconds but when I tried 'do' and 'tidy' it was running for almost 10 minutes and RStudio became unresponsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using the "dplyr" package to formatting the output. In the function that you use inside the "dlply" function you should use summary() to the lm(), so when you call "coef" it will also include the p.values.

```
test_data <- data.frame(key = c("a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b"),
                        y = c(100,180,120,60,140,200,220,240,260,280),
                        x1 = c(50,60,79,85,90,133,140,120,160,170),
                        x2 =  c(20,18,47,16,15,25,30,25,20,15))

model<-by(test_data,test_data$key,function(x)summary(lm(y~x1+x2,x)))

R2<-t(data.frame(lapply(model,function(x)x$adj.r.squared)));colnames(R2)<-"R2_adj";R2

      R2_adj
a -0.8939647
b  0.4292186

Co<-as.data.frame(t(data.frame(lapply(model,function(x)x$coef))))

colnames(Co)<-c("intercept","x1","x2")

library(dplyr)

Co%>%
        mutate(key=substr(rownames(Co),1,1),
               variable=substr(rownames(Co),3,12))%>%
        select(key,variable,intercept,x1,x2)

  key   variable   intercept         x1          x2
1   a   Estimate 162.1822438 -0.6037364  0.07628315
2   a Std..Error 141.3436897  1.8054132  2.29385395
3   a    t.value   1.1474318 -0.3344035  0.03325545
4   a   Pr...t..   0.3699423  0.7698867  0.97649134
5   b   Estimate 271.0532276  0.3624009 -3.62853907
6   b Std..Error 196.2769562  0.9166979  3.25911570
7   b    t.value   1.3809733  0.3953330 -1.11335080
8   b   Pr...t..   0.3013515  0.7307786  0.38142882
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for `plyr` I think, `sapply` will do just fine.

```
sapply(model_1, function(x) summary(x)$coefficients[, 4])

                    a         b
(Intercept) 0.3699423 0.3013515
x1          0.7698867 0.7307786
x2          0.9764913 0.3814288
```

And `t()` will get those in the same configuration as your estimates.

By the way, you may want to look at the `multidplyr` package, to do with `tidy` and `dplyr::do` after all.